# Process Bar With Process Completion Messages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I am Executing Multiple store procedures on Button click event of my .aspx page
On each Procedure Execution i have to show a message on Process baar that

process 1 is completed.
process 2 is completed.
process 3 is completed.

please help in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use an Update Panel in conjunction with Ajax Timer.

The following article may be useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc295400.aspx

The example given in the article shows you how to update a label in the Update Panel with current server time on the timer event. You can easily adapt the code to your needs and show whatever message you want to show instead of server time.

**EDIT**

As requested here is some sample code.

1. Add a new aspx file to your application and name it Test2.aspx
2. Replace the contents of aspx file as given below.
3. Run the application and see the sample code working.
4. Customize the `DoWorkAsync` method to suit your needs.
5. Run application and test your modified code.

The ASPX file:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Asynchronous Update Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="1000" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Start" /><br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Click Start button to being processing." ID="Label1" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind file:

(pay attention to inline comments)

```
Partial Class Test2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private MyAsyncProcessor As AsyncProcessor

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Session("MyAsyncProcessor") IsNot Nothing Then
            ' we are still processing.. so extract the reference of our class back from session variable
            Me.MyAsyncProcessor = Session("MyAsyncProcessor")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ' this event is fired everytime a timer ticks. 
        If MyAsyncProcessor IsNot Nothing Then
            Label1.Text = MyAsyncProcessor.StatusMessage
            If Not MyAsyncProcessor.IsProcessing Then
                MyAsyncProcessor = Nothing
                Session.Remove("MyAsyncProcessor")
                Timer1.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = ""
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        MyAsyncProcessor = New AsyncProcessor
        MyAsyncProcessor.Start()
        Session("MyAsyncProcessor") = MyAsyncProcessor  'save reference in a session variable
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class AsyncProcessor
    Public IsProcessing As Boolean
    Public StatusMessage As String

    Public Sub Start()
        Dim th As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoWorkAsync)
        th.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoWorkAsync()
        ' *** Replace this code with whatever work you want to do ***
        ' Set IsProcessing=True at beginnning of task and set it to False when exitting.
        ' Update the StatusMessage at regular intervals.

        IsProcessing = True
        For i = 1 To 10
            '' this sleep is only to simulate a long going task
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            StatusMessage &= String.Format("Task #{0} completed... <br>", i)
        Next
        StatusMessage &= "All tasks completed."
        IsProcessing = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to delegate the work to a page in an iframe. On the iframe page, as your code is processed, you can update a Session variable to contain 'Finished Processing first step' (or whatever) and use PageMethods on the parent page to call a Web Method that gets the value of the session being updated by the code on the page in the iframe.